# Calling a function on a table of async populted data in Meteor

Tags: datatable, meteor

I am using Meteor and the jquery data table library.
I have a table that I am loading meteor/handlebars using something like this:

```
<table>
{{each x}}
  // code to insert rows of data
{{/each}}
</table>
```

I need to call this on the table once it has been fully populated with data to turn it into a sortable table:

```
$('#tableID').dataTable();
```

It works when I call it from the console once the DOM is fully loaded and the data is in there, but using Template.rendered() doesn't work, nor does listening for changes with .observe since the data is loaded before that particular view is rendered.

Where can I run this code to ensure that the data is fully loaded, and if there are updates to the data in the table that it will run again?

Comment: maybe you can try observe client collection added then use DataTables api fnAddData

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way of doing it which seems to work after I split the individual rows into templates  - will update as I continue to debug it (and this is certainly not ideal).

```
Template.individualRow.rendered = function() {
  if (!$('#tableID').hasClass('initialized')) {
      $('#tableID').not('.initialized').addClass('initialized').dataTable();
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It beats me, but I can suggest a way to work around:
Do not use handlbars' helper, and observe the data, when the data changed, re-render the template manually， like this：

```
<table id="tableID"></table>

<template name="yourTemplate">
    {{#each this}}
        <tr>....</tr>
    {{/each}}
</template>


var query = ...
query.observe({
    added: function () {
        manuallyRender();
    },
    changed: function () {
        manuallyRender();
    },
    ...
});
function manuallyRender() {
    // don't need Meteor.render here, because you don't need it to be reactive.
    var frag = $(Template.yourTemplate(query.fetch()));  
    $('#tableID').empty().append(frag).dataTable();    
}
```

It should work, but maybe not the best way, any thoughts?

Actually, I think meteor has a long way to go...

Comment: I posted my solution below (although it's still super hack). Would love some thoughts as well.